Power at in half the house
Was changing a light fixture in closet, wires didn't touch, but there was a big spark. Now half the power in house doesn't work.

Something touched that was not suppose to.  A good reason you always turn off the breaker and check for no power.  Half a house is usually a bad main hot wire connection that you really do not want to play with, if you think you got a big spark, just wait for the spark from a main hot wire.  That is a big spark.

Have you checked the status of your circuit breakers? Do that and then get back to us.

Try cycling all of your breakers, including the main breaker.

There are 3 (possibly more) very different possibilities:
One Hot Main Wire Out
This is unusual. Most often this happens from a storm causing problems outside, which is normally the utility's job to fix. If this is the case then:

Roughly half the lights, receptacles and 120V appliances won't work and the other half will work.
Any 240V appliances - oven, cooktop, dryer, central HVAC, water heater - will not work properly.

One Circuit Out
This may seem like "half the house", as many older houses in particular would have only a few circuits taking care of lights and receptacles (except special things like 240V appliances) all over the house. So it may be as simple as the breaker for the light fixture tripped and now "half the house" is out.
Note that an overload on a circuit can, in addition to tripping the breaker, cause marginal parts of the circuit, such as loose wire nuts or back-stab connections, to go bad such that they don't work even after resetting the breaker.
Arc-Fault on Multiple Circuits
A newer house will typically have more circuits. But a newer house will typically also have arc fault breakers (AFCI) on many of those circuits. AFCI "listens" for the sounds of arcing. It is possible that you:

Caused an arc (or arc-like) situation when working on the light fixture
Over-sensitive AFCI breakers tripped not only for that circuit but for several other circuits

So check your breakers - all of them off and then back on, even if they don't appear to be tripped. If that doesn't fix things, check 240V appliances and see if they work or not. If 240V appliances do not work then call your utility to report an outage. If 240V appliances do work then you need to troubleshoot some more to figure out which circuit(s) are actually having problems.
